# Non-blocking methods, without parallelism

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a class with methods that must not block the execution (I guess it is called "non blocking"), but only one of those could be executing at a given time.

Suppose this:

```
import time
import random

class Foo():
    def do_stuff_a(self):
        print("Start a")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Finished a")
    
    def do_stuff_b(self):
        print("Start b")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Finished b")

def do_other_stuff():
    print("doing other stsuff")

foo = Foo()
for x in range(15):
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # These calls should be non-blocking
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
        foo.do_stuff_a()
    else:
        foo.do_stuff_b()

    do_other_stuff()
```

do_stuff_a and do_stuff_b should not block the flow, so do_other_stuff() should be executing every 0.1 seconds. Additionally, do_stuff_a and b should be skipped if there is any of them still running (i.e. methods of class Foo cannot run in parallel, if there is one running, the call to any of them should be just skipped (rather than put in a queue for later).

Any pointer friends on how to get started?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with; I need two decorators, one to manage the threading of the methods (works fine) the other one to make sure that only one method is executed, and skip the calls if it is running (rather than leaving it in a queue)

```
import time
import random
import threading

def thread(func):
    def wrapper( self, *args, **kwargs):

        th = threading.Thread(target=func,args=(self, *args))
        th.start()
    return wrapper

class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()


    def non_parallel(fun):
        def wrapper( self, *args, **kwargs):
            
            if self.lock.locked(): return
            self.lock.acquire()

            try:
                fun( self , *args)
            except ValueError as e:
                print (e)

            self.lock.release()
        return wrapper

    @thread
    @non_parallel
    def do_stuff_a(self):

        print("Start a\n")
        print("Finished a\n")
       
    
    @thread
    @non_parallel
    def do_stuff_b(self):

        print("Start b\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Finished b\n")

       

def do_other_stuff():
    print("doing other stsuff\n")

foo = Foo()
for x in range(5):
    time.sleep(0.1)

    foo.do_stuff_a()
    foo.do_stuff_b()

    do_other_stuff()
```